# Cannot Find working code for Youtube end time

Tags: youtube, powerpoint, embed

I am doing a Powerpoint presentation where I need a 30ish second clip. I have tried so many codes to get this YouTube video to stop playing but nothing seems to work. I'm using Office 365, with the newest version of PPT.
Here is the video and I need it to start at 159 and stop at 185. I have tried ?start=158&end=185 to no avail! I've tried other variations. It starts fine but won't stop!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hHdoOxs_LQ........

Here is the video and I need it to start at 159 and stop at 185. I have tried ?start=158&end=185 to no avail! I've tried other variations. It starts fine but won't stop!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hHdoOxs_LQ........

Comment: If you're looking to embed a particular segment of a YouTube video, you'll have to [download](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video) the video, crop the parts and embed the video file in your presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PowerPoint for create a sample, but, you can try and embed the video in your PowerPoint presentation as follows:

> `https://www.youtube.com/embed/3hHdoOxs_LQ?start=159&end=185&autoplay=1`

[Source](https://www.coolfundas.com/youtube-videos-how-to-set-start-and-end-time-easily/)

I tried this link in my broswer (*Google Chrome*) and it works.

It should embed the video and play the video at the given start and end time.